# Xcode: "Refactoring to new Objective-C syntax" and round brackets

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automated-refactoring

I'm wondering why Xcode refactors this

```
[self.aDictionary objectForKey:@"aKey"]
```

to this

```
(self.aDictionary)[@"aKey"]
```

and not simply

```
self.aDictionary[@"aKey"]
```

That should work fine, too, or is there anything I don't see?

Ingo.

Comment: Is it just me or is the version refactored by Xcode ugly and less readable?

Comment: @H2CO3 Well, it's not that unreadable, you end up getting used with it. It's way shorter…

Comment: Also, this brings C++-like type-dependent interpretation of operators to Objective-C which I don't consider a good feature, a change in the declaration can break all this.

Comment: probably just the personal taste of some apple engineer.

Comment: Hmmm... I still see it in Xcode 7. Time to switch to Swift, I think. ;-)